# I'm getting the result "undefined", maybe it's facing an issue with the JSON data where data is in array format. How can I solve this?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

This is the code where the console is showing undefined.

```
useEffect(() => {       
   fetch("https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_teams.php? 
         s=Soccer&c=Spain")
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.teams.strTeam)) 
    }
```

Comment: Is there anything in the response?  If so, what's the value of `data`?

Comment: If I'm doing `console.log(data.teams[1].strTeam)` , I'm receiving a string value.

Comment: Well that's your problem then.  You're trying to read the `strTeam` property of a javascript array object which does not (by default) exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Data looks like this:

```
{
 teams: [{...}, {...}]
}
```

When you want to access the `strTeam`, you have to define an index `teams[i].strTeam`.

Print all `strTeam`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
 console.log(teams[i].strTeam)
}
```